# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and SpEL?

Tags: java, configuration, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-el

Due to our rather complex `properties`-file setup we can't simply use `@PropertySource`.

Here's the properties-file:

```
connection.http.connectTimeout=15000
#connection.http.readTimeout=${connection.http.connectTimeout}
connection.http.readTimeout=#{30*1000}
```

The second line would still work and set `readTimeout` to 15000, but with the third line in place the value is just 0.

The bean classes:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("connection")
public class ConnectionConfig {

  @NestedConfigurationProperty
  private ConnectionSourceConfig http;

  public ConnectionSourceConfig getHttp() {
    return http;
  }

  public void setHttp(ConnectionSourceConfig http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

}

public class ConnectionSourceConfig {

  private long connectTimeout;

  private long readTimeout;

  public long getConnectTimeout() {
    return connectTimeout;
  }

  public void setConnectTimeout(long connectTimeout) {
    this.connectTimeout = connectTimeout;
  }

  public long getReadTimeout() {
    return readTimeout;
  }

  public void setReadTimeout(long readTimeout) {
    this.readTimeout = readTimeout;
  }

}
```

Using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` seems to stop SpEL from working:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseAppConfig {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(Environment environment) throws IOException {
    String env = getEnvProperty(environment);
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocations(getPropertiesFiles(env));
    configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    return configurer;
  }
```

I tried a fancier `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, but `convertPropertyValue()` is never called:

```
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {

      @Override
      protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        System.out.println("Parse " + originalValue);
        return super.convertPropertyValue(originalValue);
      }

    };
```

I tried to look into how Spring does its job and it seems that it works with `PropertyResolver`s. However, I don't see how I could weave one into that.

But, maybe I'm making a mistake regarding Spring's processing lifecycle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties file wise, # is considered as a comment block. Doing so, your property file ends up with a property being set to empty.

`connection.http.readTimeout=#{30*1000}`renders to `connection.http.readTimeout=` because everything after `#` is ignored.

Comment: Oh boy, such a simple answer! I completely "forgot" about that. And while saying that just look at my properties-example.... It's been there....... Great blonde moment..........

Comment: Been a pleasure to help in such a difficult moment :)